# which python different than venv

Tags: python, macos, python-venv

I followed [this guide](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) to make a sense out of all python version I have installed.
When I enter and verify the environment, I get :

```
$ pyenv version
3.7.3 (set by /Users/
```

But when I type:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

The problem came out when I wanted to run a python script, but received the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘numpy’
```

But I have (re)installed numpy from the venv with pip3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you doing this:

1. make sure you have activated your pyenv.  In order to do this go to its directory: .../pyenv and type:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

2. check for path of python executable again with:

```
$ which python
```

3. do not use pip3 (at least in in my case it has never worked properly) install it like this:

```
$ python -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Not sure why but your command went through. Thanks.

Comment: The following article might help you understand why `pip3` doesn't work: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: That article explains it perfectly.  @Py-ser python -m pip will be better because you're using the -m option, an option is something that conditionates the command: -m means 'Run the following file as a Python Script' (like if you were running it from the interpreter) so, as the article says, it gives you more control over the command conditioning you wanna do (in your case: install numpy exactly on the virtual environment)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not installed `numpy` package for the virtual environment. To properly install `numpy` for the virtual enviroment, activate it first.

`source path/to/the/venv/bin/activate`

Then type:

`pip install numpy`

Note that when you are in virtual environment, use `pip` instead of `pip3`.
Then run your python again.

`python your_file.py`

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what you mean by "activate it first". As I mentioned in my original post, I have installed numpy through pip when I was already "in" the venv. If this is not what you mean, can you please elaborate a bit more? Also, if I `pip` instead of `pip3` the numpy also results installed but with a mention that python2.7 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. I thought (from the guide I have linked in the original post), that `pyenv global 3.7.3` was enough to activate the virtual environment, but it seems I am wrong?